# Plugins don't show up after renaming plugins folder

Tags: plugins, 500-internal-error

I had to rename the wp-content/plugins folder, because I had this error 500 issue, when trying to access the /wp-admin path.

Then I logged in and renamed the wp-content/plugins folder again. Now the plugins won't show up in the plugins admin panel. If I try to re-install a plugin I have already installed, the installation fails with something like "plugin path already exists", which is obvious, because the plugin is already installed.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried to (re)install a plugin that is actually not already inside that folder? (either by deleting a plugin or installing a totally new one) That won't fix your problem by itself, but it will provide more information at least.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you named the folders to and from? List the sequence of changes carefully.

Comment: Did you try changing the permissions of your wp-admin first? Thtt usually fixes this issue. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-error-13

Comment: I renamed it to "plugins.hold" and then logged in and then back again to "plugins". And yes I can install a plugin that is not installed yet (is not in the folder)